# Convex sets and extreme points

Tags: convex-geometry

I am learning about convex sets and extreme points from a course on linear programming. I came across a theorem that states that every closed convex set has an extreme point if and only if it does not contain a line. I cannot understand what it means for the convex set to contain a line. Can you provide an example of two convex sets that do and do not contain lines?

Comment: A half plane contains lines, for example, those parallel to the line that define it. A square (boundary and interior) doesn't contain entire lines. The extreme points of the square being the vertices.

Comment: A set $C$ contains a line **iff** for some $x,y \in C$ and all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $tx+(1-t)y \in C$. The set $\{ (x,y) | x \ge 1 \}$ contains a line, the set $\{ (x,y) | x^2+y^2 \le 1 \}$ does not contain a line.